# In TypeScript how do I declare an array of functions that accept a string and return a string?

Tags: arrays, function, typescript

**UPDATE** - the context of this question was pre-TypeScript 1.4. Since that version, my first guess has been supported by the language. See the update to the answer.

---

I can declare `f` to be a function that accepts a string and returns a string:

```
var f : (string) => string
```

And I can declare `g` to be an array of string:

```
var g : string[]
```

How can I declare `h` to be an array of "function that accepts a string and returns a string"?

My first guess:

```
var h : ((string) => string)[]
```

That seems to be a syntax error. If I take away the extra parentheses then it's a function from string to array of string.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem is that the `=>` for a function type literal is itself merely syntactic sugar and doesn't want to compose with `[]`.

As the spec says:

> A function type literal of the form
>
> ( ParamList ) => ReturnType
>
> is exactly equivalent to the object type literal
>
> { ( ParamList ) : ReturnType }

So what I want is:

```
var h : { (s: string): string; }[]
```

Complete example:

```
var f : (string) => string

f = x => '(' + x + ')';

var h : { (s: string): string; }[]

h = [];

h.push(f);
```

**Update**:

Judging from [this changeset](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/914) parentheses will be allowed in type declarations in 1.4, so the "first guess" in the question will also be correct:

```
var h: ((string) => string)[]
```

**Further Update** It is in 1.4!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your research I wrote a little class PlanetGreeter/SayHello:`

```
/* PlanetGreeter */

class PlanetGreeter {
    hello    : { () : void; } [] = [];
    planet_1 : string = "World";
    planet_2 : string = "Mars";
    planet_3 : string = "Venus";
    planet_4 : string = "Uranus";
    planet_5 : string = "Pluto";
    constructor() {
        this.hello.push( () => { this.greet(this.planet_1); } );
        this.hello.push( () => { this.greet(this.planet_2); } );
        this.hello.push( () => { this.greet(this.planet_3); } );
        this.hello.push( () => { this.greet(this.planet_4); } );
        this.hello.push( () => { this.greet(this.planet_5); } );
    } 
    greet(a: string): void { alert("Hello " + a); }
    greetRandomPlanet():void { 
        this.hello [ Math.floor( 5 * Math.random() ) ] (); 
    } 
} 
new PlanetGreeter().greetRandomPlanet();
```