# A Typed array of functions

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling to figure out if it's possible in TypeScript to declare a statically typed array of functions.

For example, I can do this:

```
foo: (data:string) => void = function (data) {};
```

But if I want foo to be an array of functions that take a string and return nothing, how do I do that?

```
foo: (data:string) => void [] = [];
```

Doesn't work because TypeScript thinks it's a function that takes a string and returns an array of void, and it doesn't seem to like me trying to wrap the function in brackets.

Any ideas?

**Answer**: Thanks to mohamed below, here's an example that works in the TypeScript Playground:

```
class whatever {
public foo: { (data: string): void; }[] = [];

    dofoo() {
        for (var i=0; i < this.foo.length; i++) {
             this.foo[i]("test");
        }
    }
}

var d = new whatever();

d.foo.push(function(bar){alert(bar)})
d.foo.push(function(bar){alert(bar.length.toString())})

d.dofoo();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In TypeScript how do I declare an array of functions that accept a string and return a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706161/in-typescript-how-do-i-declare-an-array-of-functions-that-accept-a-string-and-re)

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can find this in the [language spec](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.docx) section 3.6.4:

```
foo: { (data: string): void; } []
```

Comment: Yep, that seemed to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @asawyer It has to be inside of a class or interface, and it has to have a semicolon at the end.

Comment: It can be a variable too: `var foo: { (data: string): void; } [];`

Comment: while this and the other answer both work, the compiler does not seem to always care if the type of function varies. I had made a mistake passing `() => T` to arrays that were defined as `T => void` and no compiler error was given. (maybe that is considered compatible, but even then it's still not as much type safety as you might expect)

Comment: How would you define this inside an object? E.g.: `let obj = { foo: MyFunctionType[] = [] }` ? For me, this results in an error: `'MyFunctionType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` 
`type MyFunctionType = (
  (data: string) => void
);`

Comment: link to language spec is broken

Comment: Even if this works, I find it very hard to read, especially when the function has more complicated parameters and return values. Does TypeScript offer a solution to make this more readable?

Comment: what about foo as async function? I try and not working

Comment: Broken link: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 91):

Other (newer, more readable) ways to type an array of functions using fat arrows:

```
let foo: Array<(data: string) => void>;
let bar: ((data: string) => void)[];
```

Comment: The first option here was the only syntax I could get to work with AssemblyScript.

Answer (score 15):

or `foo: ((data: string) => void)[]`

Answer (score 9):

If you wish declare an array of callable function in TypeScript, you can declare a type:

```
type Bar = (
  (data: string) => void
);
```

And then use it:

```
const foo: Bar[] = [];

const fooFn = (data: string) => console.log(data);
foo.push(fooFn);
foo.forEach((fooFn: Bar) => fooFn("Something");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type fn = (...args: any[]) => void
```