# How do I make a decorator typesafe in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, decorator

Example:

```
class Parent {
  parentMethod() {
    // ...
  }
}

@Hooks({
  // Only methods from the `Child` class (including inherited methods) must be allowed here
  childMethod: [/* ... */],
  parentMethod: [/* ... */]
})
class Child extends Parent {
  childMethod() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The `@Hooks()` decorator takes an object as an argument. In this object, keys are method names from the `Child` class. How do I make the `@Hooks()` decorator typesafe?
Could you provide a code example with types for the `@Hooks()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this if it work for you

```js
interface ClassType<T> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

type MethodKeys<T> = ({
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never
})[keyof T]

type HooksOptions<T> = {
  [K in MethodKeys<T>]: []
}

function Hooks<T>(_options: HooksOptions<T>) {
  return function (ctor: ClassType<T>): ClassType<T> {
    return ctor
  }
}

class Parent {
  parentMethod() {
    // ...
  }
}

@Hooks<Child>({
  childMethod: [/* ... */],
  parentMethod: [/* ... */]
})
class Child extends Parent {
  childMethod() {
    // ...
  }
}

@Hooks("invalid-value") // error
class Child2 extends Parent {
  childMethod() {
    // ...
  }
}


@Hooks<Child3>({
  c: [], // error
  childMethod: [/* ... */],
  childMethod2: [/* ... */], // error
  parentMethod: [/* ... */]
})

class Child3 extends Parent {
  public c: string = ''
  childMethod() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: I like your solution, but if the generic type for `@Hooks<GenericType>` isn't specified, TypeScript won't force you to specify it, and the `@Hooks` will accept **any** arguments as valid.

See [example](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F3nzKiM0)

Comment: @Mike answer updated. TS will now force to pass the generics

Answer (score 0):

There are no types for methods of a certain class in typescript(never heard of such types in other languages as well TBH),
You can give a type to a function signature.

Edit :
Well apperantly there are some tricks i wasn't aware of
,as seen in other answers..
But if youre intrested in a fast simple yet limited solution:

For example :

```
let myAdd: (baseValue: number, increment: number) => number = (baseValue, increment) => baseValue + increment
```

More info of typed fuctions here :
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

If that suffices use the typed signature on the declaration of the decorator like so :

```
Interface ObjectInterface {
   ChildMethods: {(param) => void} [], //or whatever fuction signature meets your need, this is just an example.
   ParentMethods: {(param) => void}[]
}

//this is the decorator declaration
function Hooks(obj: ObjectInterface) {
  return function (
    target,
    propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) {
    // what ever implementation you have in hooks...
  };
}
```

This way when passing functions that are not of type`(param) => void` to the decorator should result in a compilation error.

More info here :
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

And here for typed fuctions array like i did on `ObjectInterface`:
[A Typed array of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12734660/14066176)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
interface Type<T> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

type HookMap<T> = {
  [func in keyof T]?: any[];
};

function Hooks<T>(hookMap: HookMap<T>) {
  return (clazz: Type<T>): void => {
    // ...
  };
}

class Parent {
  parentMethod() {
    // ...
  }
}

@Hooks({
  childMethod: [/* ... */],
  parentMethod: [/* ... */]
})
class Child extends Parent {
  childMethod() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEA8qB8yEAHpCACYDOyAYgK4gJjAD2IyA3gLABQy-yEBADuyABQA6KXCgBzSgC5kcEOgDaAXQCUS1AG5eAX168wWFAAkWLANYBZOJjyEAvJ1781MBgmShkNhDoLDBoGgD8SirqGgY8hnG83ozMbMhWtpTOYgAW1vaOShkFTgRa7nzIUBBgdFDsYggANnAAXq265s46yABuLMDkyC6E3JX8APQTyFISHsgJRiY8zXCU1AAKMhDgFfyY2%20B2NXnkYuVjAshTM1LzxvHLAALFlGKXyAg5wE3kx2CnJRqCYAKluEmQIImGgANPMDtUjicWOQgaDwZDoUYtLxVutkABhb6-IikHZUZBbRFgPafYl-ZFnC7zSbTWb3IxAA)

Comment: Well, this will allow the properties declared in the Child and Parent class to be used in the decorator object. In the question, the solution should have contain only method names.

Comment: @ShivamSingla Yes, I agree. But I was unable to integrate your `MethodKeys` type to my solution. See [example](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F3nDJea7)