# TypeScript array of functions

Tags: arrays, function, types, typescript, type-alias

I was wondering how could one declare a typed-function array in TypeScript.

For instance, say I have a field which can hold a function that has no arguments and returns void:

```
private func: () => void;
```

Now, say I wanted a field which can hold an array of such functions:

```
private funcs: () => void  [];
```

This is obviously the wrong way to do what I intended since the compiler considers this to be a function which returns an array of voids.

Trying to isolate the inline prototype declaration with parentheses as in:

```
private funcs2: (  () => void  ) [];
```

causes a compiler error.

Does anyone have an idea of how this could be accomplished ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12706161/24874

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You'll need to use the full type literal syntax instead of the `=>` shorthand:

```
private funcs: { (): void; }[];
```

You could also make an interface if that looks too weird:

```
// (elsewhere at top-level)
interface foo {
    (): void;
}

class etc {
    private funcs: foo[];
}
```