# In TypeScript, how do I declare a function that returns a string type array?

Tags: arrays, typescript

**Possible duplicates:**

*[In TypeScript how do I declare an array of functions that accept a string and return a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706161/in-typescript-how-do-i-declare-an-array-of-functions-that-accept-a-string-and-re)*: In this post user talking about return string array from a function using lamda expression.

*[How to declare Return Types for Functions in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736269/how-to-declare-return-types-for-functions-in-typescript)*: In this post, the user is talking about (how I can declare a return type of the function) as mentioned in his post.

Both the above links are not possible duplicates against my question. So let's get started.

What I was expecting in my code: A function that returns a string array, for example, `public _citiesData: string[];`.

I have a TypeScript class definition that starts like this:

```
export class AppStartupData {
public _citiesData: string[];

constructor() {
    this.citiesData();
}

    citiesData():string[] {
        return this._citiesData.push('18-HAZARI','A.K','ABBOTABAD');
    }
}
```

I am getting an error while building my code:

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string[]'

Comment: `string[]` **is** how you type an array of strings. Please give a [mcve] for the message you're receiving

Comment: @jonrsharpe above error is which I was received while build my code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe please give me an example on how we declare class functions in typescript which return type is array. If I run my above code it shows me error which I described.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your error is because you're returning the value of the push method.

The push method [returns the new length of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Return_value) and that's why it's trying to convert a number to an array of strings.

So, what you should do is this:

```
citiesData():string[] {
    this._citiesData.push('18-HAZARI','A.K','ABBOTABAD');
    return this._citiesData;
}
```

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan at a guess, because *"its a little bit different"* doesn't actually explain **how** it's different, and you didn't actually include the full traceback that would have helped pinpoint the error.